How to fix the "connection pool timeout" error in Go Redis?
My project involved microservices architecture, each written in Golang. All of those microservices creates individual clients (in the beginning) of a common Redis hosted on a separate node in K8s. We use go-redis library for this purpose. Now, while creating the Redis client, we don't specify any option except the host:port address and the pool size for each client in microservice is 10 (which is the default one).
Here's the code for that:
cli := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     config.Url,
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
})
if _, err := cli.Ping(ctx).Result(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
}

Few months ago, we encountered a high traffic in our system i.e. around roughly 2 million requests on Redis server in 1 hour. Out of that: 620k requests were of cache miss, 50k requests were of cache invalidate, 180k requests were of cache set, 1.2 million requests were of cache get and others.
Now, here's what happened: Frontend called POST API A1 of our gateway microservice M1. A1 API called POST API A2 of microservice M2 and A2 called a GET API A3 of microservice M3. This API A3 was called approx 200k times in 1 hour. This API A3 simply fetches data from Redis. Since our entire system is dependent on Redis, we started getting this error on Redis GET Command - "redis: connection pool timeout". Here's the code of GET cache:
val, err := cli.Slave.Get(*ctx, request.Key).Bytes()
if err == redis.Nil {
        common.LogCache(ctx, common.LogCacheMiss, "somekey")
        return nil, nil
} else if err != nil {
        return nil, err
}
return val, nil

I haven't been able to find the reason for why it happened. I checked the Redis info of my server and got to know that we have max clients limit of 10 000. Also, the average connected clients at a particular instance of time in Redis is 300-400. We have around 2.5 million keys and are using around 8.6 GB memory out of total 12 GB. In this duration, over 200k cache requests gave a latency of more than 3 seconds.
I also tried Redis benchmarking on this Redis server with the criteria of 100k requests, 10 clients, data size = 1 MB, keys = 2.5 million but it is giving p99 results with max of 3 ms. I was thinking of increasing the pool size but I believe it won't do any good as mentioned in the official documentation of go-redis.
I am unable to find the cause why I got this error and how should I fix it in future, if it arises again. Can anyone please help?

Please avoid using local words like lakh here. Rest of the world does not use them, or understand them.

redis: connection pool timeout can occur when there is no free connection in the pool. It means your redis is too busy, or connections are not retrieved properly. I think the former one looks reasonable because you said it happened when there was a traffic spike in your service.

How about the cpu usage of your redis?

@nimdrak CPU usage was not that high and was average

I see. How about in the CPU usage of clients at that time? And are you using sentinel configuration? Why did you request to a Slave like cli.Slave.Get, not Master?

actually slave and master are same for now. so you can ignore it. Our microservices are hosted on different pods under same nodes in K8S. At that time, we observed that the CPU usage of one of the nodes reached 100%. So, we increased the number of nodes as well as number of pods for one of our microservices.

Why don't you try with below: cli := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{     Addr:        config.Url,     Password:    "",     DB:          0,     PoolSize:    50,         // Increased pool size     MinIdleConns: 20,        // Minimum number of idle connections     IdleTimeout: 5 * time.Minute,  // Timeout for idle connections     PoolTimeout: 30 * time.Second, // Timeout for getting a connection from the pool })
